# aws iam policy for denying users creating new roles only with my boundary policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I want to create a policy where the user is restricted from creating a role without my permission boundary! i tried using iam:AttachRolePolicy and Iam:putRolePermissionBoundary but not working still!

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on without seeing what you were trying to do. Could you add the full policy you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config you are attempting would be accomplished if you granted the user the **iam:CreateRole** permission with a condition. For example if your permission boundary is a a policy called **myPermissionBoundary** then attaching the policy below would allow the user to create a role IFF the user also attached the permission boundary to that role.

```
{
      "Sid": "CreateRoleIffPermInPlace",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateRole"
      ],
      "Resource": *,
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/myPermissionBoundary"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Good to know. Could you share what your solution is? You should add it here as a solution to your own question.